# Como sumarizar dados no R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho uma amostra de dados de compras e gostaria de saber quantas compras tiveram por usuário no total.

dput para auxiliar a resposta:

```
structure(list(USUARIO = c(931053L, 276977L, 354508L, 909717L, 
69758L, 104827L, 6600051L, 5035952L, 335505L, 340387L, 103130L, 
317058L, 424447L, 6862455L, 5040771L, 2360439L, 346941L, 426400L, 
271410L, 809550L, 96394L, 161292L, 752270L, 3703472L, 260921L, 
20557L, 291092L, 806951L, 82997L, 984555L, 5080457L, 31454L, 
5123415L, 498622L, 786436L, 320239L, 29603L, 6583452L, 304246L, 
6734562L, 101254L, 516730L, 37847L, 6928520L, 7705558L, 299285L, 
7760544L, 7760206L, 377014L, 104312L, 433721L, 87913L, 6732808L, 
633687L, 7526265L, 5038688L, 7500519L, 6640730L, 420430L, 47049L, 
7699248L, 6898123L, 7698394L, 7723798L, 577026L, 296424L, 165665L, 
152160L, 797450L, 90960L, 352622L, 6827072L, 7812492L, 532571L, 
6795263L, 7611543L, 429681L, 21840L, 6683144L, 18176L, 389995L, 
748456L, 423368L, 325129L, 7541131L, 186283L, 7795747L, 6760326L, 
6849786L, 202426L, 56131L, 676905L, 7550723L, 258189L, 123517L, 
368966L, 373162L, 183484L, 7583616L, 7716239L), DATA = structure(c(17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731
), class = "Date"), VL_PED_PG = c(20, 20, 50, 20.32, 20, 30, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 50, 30, 50, 30, 20, 
30, 20, 30, 50, 30, 50, 50, 46, 50, 30, 50, 15, 20, 30, 50, 20, 
30, 30, 50, 50, 20, 50, 46, 50, 48, 49, 40, 20, 50, 50, 20, 30, 
40, 49, 8, 16, 49, 20, 40, 16, 16, 46, 20, 10, 50, 20, 50, 12, 
30, 48, 6, 50, 30, 49, 10, 20, 20, 30, 12, 50, 30, 30, 26, 50, 
26, 50, 50, 10, 10, 30, 46, 20, 15, 50, 20, 20, 26, 16)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Estou tentando utilizar `summarise` do pacote `dplyr` mas estou com dificuldade de como posso usá-la. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Você quer saber o número de compras por usuário, onde cada usuário pode ser considerado um grupo, pois ele faz varias compras? Se sim, este conjunto de dados fornecido não faz sentido algum, pois nele cada usuário é único. E, qual é a variável "compras"?

Comment: olá, é que a base de dados é muito grande, mas com os dados completos os usuários repetem sim, no caso essa amostra possui apenas 100 linhas.

Comment: Entendo. Dê uma olhada na resposta do @Tomás, pois ela atende o que você pede.

Comment: Vou testar com a base completa. muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) funciona assim. Você agrupa os dados pela sua unidade de análise, no caso `USUARIO` e então cria um sumário dos dados para aquela unidade de análise.

Neste caso temos

```
library(dplyr)
dados %>% 
  group_by(USUARIO) %>% 
  summarise(quantidade = n())

# A tibble: 100 x 2
   USUARIO quantidade
     <int>      <int>
 1   18176          1
 2   20557          1
 3   21840          1
 4   29603          1
 5   31454          1
 6   37847          1
 7   47049          1
 8   56131          1
 9   69758          1
10   82997          1
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Um ótimo material sobre o `dplyr` em português pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://www.curso-r.com/material/manipulacao/). Esta [cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) também pode ser útil.

O `dplyr` também oferece uma função de utilidade que conta a ocorrência de cada valor único de uma variável no `data.frame`. Trata-se da função `count()`. Sua sintaxe é passar o `data.frame` como primeiro argumento e depois elencar as variáveis que  compõe a unidade de análise para fazer a contagem. Usando-a teríamos:

```
dados %>% count(USUARIO)

# A tibble: 100 x 2
   USUARIO     n
     <int> <int>
 1   18176     1
 2   20557     1
 3   21840     1
 4   29603     1
 5   31454     1
 6   37847     1
 7   47049     1
 8   56131     1
 9   69758     1
10   82997     1
# ... with 90 more rows
```

A função `count()` possui um argumento `sort`, que deve ser passado explicitamente, que ordena o resultado no maior `n` para o menor.